Comedy where kid gets ham from his father as Christmas/birthday gift
I'm trying to find this american comedy movie where a character remembers himself as a kid in front the TV and his insensitive father (possibly drunk) barges in and throws a cold ham or similar piece of meat in front of him as a birthday/Christmas gift. The scene is traumatizing for the kid, who was expecting a toy or something like that.
That's the only scene I can remember. Does it sound familiar to anyone?
EDIT: It was a hollywood movie. I watched it in the 90's (turns out the movie is from 1988).

@NapoleonWilson Please verify if the edit suffices to put the question on-topic. Thank you.

This sounds very much like a scene from Scrooged, starring Bill Murray. The father comes in and says, "Here Francis, I've got something for you. Merry Christmas." He drops a wrapped package in 4-year-old Francis's lap.  It contains 5 pounds of veal, rather than that choo-choo train that Francis was hoping for. Here's the scene on YouTube:




That's definitely it! Thank you very much!

Thanks! Fun bit of trivia: the dad was played by Bill Murray's brother, Brian Doyle-Murray.  They also appeared together in movie Groundhog Day - Brian Doyle-Murray was the grand marshal of the Groundhog Day ceremony.
